# Filter proprites from array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this data coming from backend

```
[ { "total_spent": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "cart_value": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "shipping_price": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "product": [ "in" ] }, { "customer_type": [ "equal_to" ] } ]
```

And I am trying only to get total_spent and product and delete the rest.

I tried the following but I think it applies to objects.

```
filterConfi() {
      return ["cart_value", "shipping_price"].forEach(
         e => delete this.config.segmentationConfiguration[e]
      );
    },
```

The final result should look something like this

```
[ { "total_spent": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "product": [ "in" ] }, { "customer_type": [ "equal_to" ] } ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const arr = [ { "total_spent": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "cart_value": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "shipping_price": [ "greater_than", "less_than", "equal_to", "between" ] }, { "product": [ "in" ] }, { "customer_type": [ "equal_to" ] } ]

console.log(arr.filter(x=> !!x.total_spent || !!x.product))
```

Comment: Do not need the double `!!`. You can remove it